# Difference between accessing via property access and destructuring in kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin

I have a `data class` like this

```
data class Task(
    var id: Int,
    var description: String,
    var priority: Int
)
```

I implement it the following

```
val foo = Task(1, "whatever", 10)
```

I read about accessing `whatever` like this

```
foo.description
```

or

```
foo.component2()
```

What is the difference?

Comment: In practice you never use `component2()` yourself. It's just a necessity to make destructuring posible

Comment: Why would you ever *want* to access `description` by explicitly calling `component2`? `component2` is supposed to be called implicitly when you use the destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in behaviour, but use `foo.description`.

It's extremely rare to use a `componentN()` function directly. If you know which component you're accessing, it's just way more readable to use the property directly.

The `componentN()` functions are mostly a tool to implement actual destructuring declarations like:

```kotlin
val (id, desc, prio) = task
```

Which is a shortcut that is equivalent to:

```kotlin
val id = task.component1()
val desc = task.component2()
val prio = task.component3()
```

..which you should probably never write in source code.